# Why is git showing files as deleted and new instead of diff?

Tags: git

Somehow when committing a change, git shows a file as "deleted", and shows the same file as "added", instead of showing a diff.
For example :

(-)file.txt

```
- hello world
- this is amazing
- some more text
```

(+)file.txt

```
+ hello world
+ this is amazing
```

Instead of showing

(+-) file.txt

```
hello world
this is amazing
- some more text
```

Do you have any idea what is causing this? I do not know exactly how this commit was submitted, but it looks like it somehow lost track of the deltas.

Comment: `git` never shows messages like these, especially with `(+-)`. If you show actual message, we might be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because of different line endings. You need to tell git to handle that differences:

`$ git config --global core.autocrlf input`
`# Set this setting on OSX or Linux`

`$ git config --global core.autocrlf true`
`# Set this setting on Windows`